# compare strings and delete part of the string

Tags: php

I have strings like this

```
$title = "1 Gal. Black PE Grow Bag (100 per pack)";

$quantity = "10";
```

I want to check is string title contains string quantity. If dont then delete text in brackets, if yes title will be the same. I did something like this, but dont work good for me:

```
  if (strpos($title, quantity) !== false) {

    }
else{
   $title = preg_replace('/\([\s\S]+?\)/', '', $title);
}
```

In this example quantity is not contained in the string title. There is number 100 in the string title, but that is not the same, but i should add condition for that also??

Comment: `10` is in `100` ...

Comment: also your `quantity` in your conditional is missing a `$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually very close. All you need is a space in your code and it will work.
Notice the space in the strpos.
This will make sure it's 10 and not 10 in 100 since we have a space after the 10.

```
$title = "1 Gal. Black PE Grow Bag (100 per pack)";

$quantity= "10";
if (strpos($title, $quantity . " ") !== false) {

}else{
    $title = preg_replace('/\([\s\S]+?\)/', '', $title);
}
echo $title;
```

I created a demo of how it handles 10/100.

https://3v4l.org/ZdYFk

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex since its a small simple string..

```
\(.*\)
```

Also, I like to use online regex editors such as https://www.phpliveregex.com/

You can see it in action on your code here https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/pSx

So the whole code can look like this

```
if ($quantity === 0){
$title = preg_replace("/\(.*\)/","", $title);
}
```

this is assuming you use 0 when the item is out of stock.

Comment: You should use a non-greedy quantifier in case there are two sets of parentheses in the string.

Comment: His problem is with matching the number `10`, not doing the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I made this into a working function:

```
<?php
    function checkQty($title, $qty)
    {
        $words = explode(' ', $title);
        $endKey = end(array_keys($words));

        foreach ($words as $key => $word)
        {
            if (strpos($word, '(') !== false) {
                $word = str_replace('(', '', $word);
            }

            if (is_numeric($word)) {
                $word = (int) $word;
            }

            if ((int) $qty === $word) {
                $toDelete = range($key, $endKey);
            }
        }

        if (!empty($toDelete)) {
            foreach ($toDelete as $key => $del)
            {
                unset($words[$del]);
            }
        }

        return trim(implode(' ', $words));
    }

    $title = "1 Gal. Black PE Grow Bag (100 per pack)";
    $quantity = "100";

    echo '<pre>'. print_r(checkQty($title, $quantity), 1) .'</pre>';

    $quantity = '10';
    echo '<pre>'. print_r(checkQty($title, $quantity), 1) .'</pre>';
```

this goes through each word in the title, if the string is a numeric value, convert to int and compare to the quantity. If quantity matches the value, create a range of the key to the end key of the exploded array and delete if `$toDelete` contains values.

Comment: You know you can use `elseif`?

Comment: @Andreas no need - first if converts to number with bracket, second converts the value to int and last compares that to the qty - they're not running off each other

Comment: This dont work for me, can you give an online example?

Comment: @doki huh, weird tested in my localhost what errors come up?

Answer (score 0):

You should turn `$quantity` into a regular expression, then you can use the word boundary escape sequences to make it match a whole word, not part of a word.

```
$quantity = '/\b10\b/';
if (!preg_match($quantity, $title)) {
    $title = preg_replace('/\(.+?\)/s', '', $title);
}
```

And instead of using `[\s\S]` in the regexp, you can use `.` along with the `s` modifier; that makes `.` match anything, including newlines.

Comment: ERROR : preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: Needed delimiters in `$quantity`, I've updated the answer.